# Is a bathroom with only a shower a "full bath"?

Tags: bathroom

My town just has "full bath" and "half bath" assessment categories. I have two bathrooms with a shower but no tub, so technically they are 3/4 baths. Should these be counted as "full baths" or "half baths"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a "marketing" question in terms of how realtors advertise, and not a Home Improvement question.

Comment: @SolarMike This is not about advertising. This is about how the property is recorded on town assessment records.

Comment: So, still not Home Improvement, but others will decide.

Comment: Will depend on what legal definitions your town uses, next town over they might be different.  Ask your town what it considers a full bathroom to contain.

Comment: In my area a 1/2 bath is a toilet and a basin. Adding a shower or a tub they are then called full baths

Comment: Depends on agency definition. For instance HUD in some documents doesn't recognize fractional bathrooms. *Bathroom. A bathroom which
includes a water closet (toilet),
lavatory (sink), and bathtub or
shower* and *Powder Room. A room with
only a water closet (toilet) and
lavatory (sink)* huduser.gov/portal/publications/fairch7.pdf . (Shouldn't a sink and toilet be 2/3?)

Comment: Around here in Calif,  a room with a lavatory, toilet, and shower is a ¾ bath.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Yeah, I said that, but the town database just has two categories: full and half.

Answer (score 4):

Your town, as reported by you:

- A room for the elimination of bodily waste, and hand-washing (limited face, etc.) as well
  afterwards. Half-bath, or "powder room"
- A room for the above plus washing the entire body. Full-Bath.

Clearly, your town **does not care** if you wash yourself in a tub or a shower. They probably don't care if you have a tub **and** a separate shower, a toilet **and** a separate bidet, or **how many basins** your lavatory sink has. It's a **functional** assessment, and there is no 3/4 bath in that assessment. You either have a place to wash your entire self more functionally than with a washcloth standing on the floor in front of the lavatory sink in a half-bath, or you don't.

Comment: Ok, so the upshot is that the likelihood is that EITHER a bathtub or shower constitutes a full bath?

Comment: Aha, I always thought half and full refer to the fixtures... perhaps more insightful to view them as refering to the *body*!

Comment: One, the other, the common tub-with-shower, or both separately.  And the next town over might be the same, or different. Which doesn't matter to you unless the town line gets moved.